# how to add c++ library to compiler on a public linux/unix cluster

Tags: c++, linux, unix, compiler-construction, path

I'm using the school public cluster and want to include c++ library paths to the c++ compiler. I've installed boost, armadillo and so on. After make them, the program told me to add the header path to the c++ compiler. As I'm in a public cluster, how can I do that? Obviously I do not have sudo or yum authorities.

Comment: I think you'll need to talk to the school rather than ask random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: -I/path/to/the/headers (depending on the compiler you are using)?

Comment: Not voting to close this, your question could be better phrased as "How to add header paths to a c++ project without su rights".  Akluth's comment is likely your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-I/home/username/where/your/directories/are/include` for headers

`-L/home/username/where/your/directories/are/lib` for your libraries

From here, if you want to run your executables, you have two options:

1. Update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `/home/username/where/your/directories/are/lib`
2. In your compile line add: `-Wl,-rpath,/home/username/where/your/directories/are/lib`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your shell's startup file (.bashrc if you use bash) to set compilier environment variables for C, C++ and the linker. If you're using gcc, see this [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html).

```
CPATH
C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
```